Global State management in sveltekit
im using sveltekit with superforms, i want t implement a global state manager using a store, the problem is when i try to access the return from +page.server.ts i get a value of undefined
    add: async ({ request, locals }: { request: Request, locals: any }) => {
        const boardAdderForm = await superValidate(request, zod(boardAdderSchema));

        if (!boardAdderForm.valid) {
            return fail(400, {
                boardAdderForm
            });
        }
        try {
            const { board_name, board_columns } = boardAdderForm.data;

            const newDash = await createDashBoard({
                boardName: board_name,
                userId: locals.user.id,
            });
            if (board_columns) {
                const catArr = await createCategoryHelper(board_columns, newDash[0].id)
                await createCategory(catArr)
            }
            const board = await getBoardById(newDash[0].id)
            return message(boardAdderForm, board)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error in dashboard: ', e);
        }
    },

and inside src/lib/components/ui/BoardAdder.svelte
  const { form: Aform, enhance, message } = superForm(boardAdderForm, {
    dataType: "json",
  });

  function sendBoard() {
    const board = $message.board
    dispatch('boardAdded', board)
  }


yet message is undefined, and i have no idea why
and this is how im planning to update the state manager
  function addBoard(event) {
    stateManager.addBoard(event.detail)
    console.log(" ~ addBoard ~ detail:", event.detail)
  }
  $: allBoards = $stateManager

this is the repo.
thank you for help in advance
i tried updating the store right in the form action but apparently its not the best practice to use stores in server side so that aint an option.
also my apologies if the project structure is out of place, this is my first big project
anyhow thank you for your time

If a page is dependent on a store to provide its main functionality, then it is OK to use the store, and instead disable server-side rendering for that page. But if you can design your solution so that pages can be server-side rendered without using a store, that will give you the benefits of faster loading, and search engines will better understand your page content, etc.

@PeppeL-G  i tried to do that but didnt exactly function the way it should the closest i got is using a global variable inside +page.server.ts named board that takes the output of getBoardById and return it in the load function as data.board but its always behind with one element
but logically
return message(boardAdderForm, board)
this line should return newly created board inside the message store so i can access it as $message.board but for some reason i get undefined to $message

Would generally advise against using global state, it is often a security/privacy risk since it will be shared across users on the server.
